# WSO2 APIM 4.1.0 not starting properly

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

we are working on wso2 APIM 4.1.0. APIM not starting properly due to below error.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-08-03 03:30:27,825] ERROR {Events.Framework} - FrameworkEvent ERROR org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.notification [277]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl; version="[9.0.0,10.0.0)"
    -> Export-Package: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl; bundle-symbolic-name="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl"; bundle-version="9.20.74.106"; version="9.20.74.106"; uses:="javax.xml.namespace,org.apache.axiom.om,org.apache.commons.logging,org.json.simple,org.json.simple.parser,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.dto,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.model,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.model.botDataAPI,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.model.graphql.queryanalysis,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.model.policy,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.model.webhooks,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.definitions,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dto,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.monetization,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.recommendationmgt,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.persistence.exceptions,org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects,org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.generic,org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.generic.dataobjects,org.wso2.carbon.registry.api,org.wso2.carbon.registry.core,org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions,org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.service,org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session,org.wso2.carbon.user.api"
       org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl [272]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth; version="[6.0.0,7.0.0)"
           -> Export-Package: org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth; bundle-symbolic-name="org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth"; bundle-version="6.4.176.9"; version="6.4.176.9"; uses:="com.nimbusds.jwt,org.apache.commons.logging,org.wso2.carbon.core,org.wso2.carbon.core.common,org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.model,org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.model,org.wso2.carbon.identity.base,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.dao,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.dto,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.model,org.wso2.carbon.identity.openidconnect.model,org.wso2.carbon.user.core"
              org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth [484]
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: waffle.util; version="[1.6.0,2.0.0)"
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.cache; version="[6.0.0,7.0.0)"
           -> Export-Package: org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.cache; bundle-symbolic-name="org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth"; bundle-version="6.4.176.9"; version="6.4.176.9"; uses:="org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.model,org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.cache,org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.model,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.dao,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.bean,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.model,org.wso2.carbon.identity.openidconnect.model"
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao; version="[9.0.0,10.0.0)"
    -> Export-Package: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao; bundle-symbolic-name="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl"; bundle-version="9.20.74.106"; version="9.20.74.106"; uses:="org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple,org.json.simple,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.dto,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.model,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.model.botDataAPI,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.model.graphql.queryanalysis,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.model.policy,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.model.subscription,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.model.webhooks,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.certificatemgt.exceptions,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dto,org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.gatewayartifactsynchronizer.environmentspecificproperty"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
```

please help me solve this issue.

Comment: What is your JDK version (mention the specific version including the patch version)

Comment: we are using openjdk version "11.0.20" 2023-07-18. APIM started properly till yesterday. we observing this issue today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/76819977/10055162

This WSO2 product startup failure encounters when using the latest JDK versions 11 (JDK 11.0.20) and 17 (JDK 17.0.8+9). This is due to a fix that has been implemented by JDK [1].

According to the JDK release notes [2] [3], we can disable these newly introduced validations to preserve backward compatibility. These validations can be disabled by adding the following parameters to    `$JAVA_VER_BASED_OPTS` defined in server startup file (api-manager.sh) located in the <WSO2_PRODUCT_HOME>/bin directory. Please stop the server and apply the parameters and start the server again.

```
-Djdk.util.zip.disableZip64ExtraFieldValidation=true \
-Djdk.nio.zipfs.allowDotZipEntry=true \
```

[1] - https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8251329

[2] - https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11-0-20-relnotes.html

[3] - https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/17all-relnotes.html

Comment: Thank you. After adding above configuration APIM  started properly. But, APIM started properly without above configuration earlier. we observed this issue today only. could you please explain more about this issue and provided solution.

Comment: The problem you have encountered arises when the underlying JDK is automatically updated and applies certain patches, particularly those that have been integrated in the versions JDK 11.0.20 and JDK 17.0.8.

You might not have encountered this problem before because your system might have been running on an older version of the JDK that did not include these changes. However, once your system performed an automatic JDK update and applied the patches, these issues would have started occurring.