# Getting Error while running open source build of wso2 APIM4.2.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have built 4.2.0 API from official Git and trying to run it using api-manager.sh

/wso2am-4.2.0-SNAPSHOT/bin$ sh api-manager.sh
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /home/ashutosh_singla/wso2am-4.2.0-SNAPSHOT
Using Java memory options: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [log4j2] ERROR : Unrecognized format specifier [appName]
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [log4j2] ERROR : Unrecognized conversion specifier [appName] starting at position 26 in conversion pattern.
[2023-08-18 00:18:22,710] ERROR - Framework FrameworkEvent ERROR
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.wso2.carbon.addressing [97]
Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.axis2; version="[1.6.1,1.7.0)"
-> Export-Package: org.apache.axis2; bundle-symbolic-name="axis2"; bundle-version="1.6.1.wso2v83"; version="1.6.1.wso2v83"; uses:="javax.xml.namespace,org.apache.axiom.om,org.apache.axiom.soap,org.apache.axis2.context,org.apache.axis2.description,org.apache.axis2.namespace"

========================================================
**Config I have**
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.18" 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.18+10-post-Debian-1deb11u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.18+10-post-Debian-1deb11u1, mixed mode, sharing)

Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.18, vendor: Debian, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.10.0-24-cloud-amd64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

===========================================================

Tried adding java version opts as well by following. [WSO2 APIM 4.1.0 not starting properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76824999/wso2-apim-4-1-0-not-starting-properly/76825346#76825346)